# Shiny browser(), giving no logic results with if sentence

Tags: if-statement, browser, shiny

I am creating a Shiny application and when I am debugging with the browser() function I have errors with the if-statement

For example, if I write this (complete example below):

```
if(1 < 2) 
 {
      h <- 5
 }
```

And I receive this:
debug at #3: h <- 5

What could be wrong? It looks that if-statment doesn't work inside the browser. 
Thanks

```
library(shiny)


# Global variables can go here
n <- 200


# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
  plotOutput('plot')
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {

  browser()
  if(1 < 2) 
  {
    h <- 5
  }

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(runif(input$n))
  })
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You really need to elaborate, it is impossible to tell you what is wrong with so little information. Note that `browser()` allows you to run your code step-by-step. The fact that it stops on `h <- 5` does not indicate this line is wrong. What is the error you are encountering? Can you post a reproducible example? Is this really related to shiny?

Comment: I edited with a complete example. Thanks.